# Can we use integrate zoom_sdk into flutter app?

Tags: flutter, zoom-sdk

If the answer is yes....I'm getting several errors while importing packages even after adding dependencies in pubspec.yaml file.

for the entire integration I followed
(https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_zoom_sdk)

## **After that I have seen a post in  **

(https://devforum.zoom.us/t/flutter-official-zoom-support/67431) saying they are still working on it.
Can anyone please help me with this? If possible sharing of any sample code would be highly appreciated.

sample code for the zoom_sdk integration into flutter after clicking a button(onPressed())

Comment: Please Add more details about the error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you can integrate zoom sdk using native code